# NFS Permissions get Reset as Non-Root User

Tags: server, permissions, mount, 18.04, nfs

## NFS Question

I'm trying to mount a network drive on a nearly fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 Server, and I'm getting some puzzling behavior.

I mount the drive as root, and list the permissions:

```
# mount xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/my/share /mnt/nfs
# ls /mnt
drwxrwxr-x  1   user    user    nfs

# cd /mnt/nfs
```

Looks good so far! (you'll see why I do that `cd` in just a second...)

I log in as a normal user, `user`, and try to go about my business:

```
$ ls /mnt
drwxrwxr-x  1   user    user    nfs

$ cd /mnt/nfs
cd: test: Permission denied

$ ls /mnt
d---------  1   user    user    nfs
```

Uhh... what happened to the permissions?
The process is thankfully reversible... Well, only if `root` tries it...

```
# ls /mnt
d---------  1   user    user    nfs

# cd /mnt/nfs
# pwd
/mnt/nfs

# ls /mnt
drwxrwxr-x  1   user    user    nfs
```

Any ideas what's going on, and how I can go about fixing it? I'm at a complete loss.

It's worth noting that this is the second machine that this has happened to me with Ubuntu 18.04 Server, both nearly out of the box.

*note:* The command output is simulated, but taken almost directly from the server. (ie: the number of hard links `ls` reports is probably not right, and I omitted the `.` and `..` directories, but the permissions, owners, etc. are correct)

Comment: I think `/mnt` belongs to root which is probably why you cannot access the contents (?) I had a similar issue when trying to mount an nfs drive in `/mnt` My suggestion would be to make a temporary folder in `~/` mount it and see if the problem persists. You also might want to try `sshfs` if you plan on opening up the server to the internet as nfs wasn't meant for this purpose and isn't as secure as `sshfs`

Comment: I checked the permissions on `/mnt`, and while `root:root` owns it, the permissions are `755`, so I should be able to access folders inside of it regardless (and I tested this by making a folder inside of it and I was able to access it)... Unfortunately this folder is actually going to be said user's home, so he doesn't have another home to make a mount point in at the minute. If you think it's necessary, I'll set something up.

I also can't use `sshfs` because the host is a Synology disk, but it's on an internal network so it should be fine.

Comment: hmmm what does `/etc/exports` look like? And I would try to set something up just so we can say for certain that it's not just a permissions issue. I spent longer than I am willing to admit on something similar to this but I can't remember if I mounted in`/mnt` or probably something more likely `/run/media...`

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature of `NFS`, called "Root squashing". See http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/nfs.htm the section "`User ID Mapping Options`".

The "Root squashing" feature was added to prevent `root` on other systems from accessing files as `root` on the NFS server. The NFS protocol doesn't have any authentication, and would blindly accept an NFS packet saying "I am [`UID=root`,`GID=root`] write this data to `/etc/passwd`", without "Root squashing". With "Root squashing", the packet becomes "I am [`UID=nobody`, `GID=nobody`] write this data to `/etc/passwd`", a *much* safer command (that will fail).

Comment: I've already played around with the squashing options on the server, and it didn't seem to alleviate the problem -- notice that `root` _can_ access the share, it's the normal user that has problems. I've also made sure the the uid/gid of the normal user matches what's on the shared server. Some of the things in that link do sound really familiar though, so I'll play with it when I get the chance (probably tomorrow).